# Factorization of characters

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, topological-groups

Linked to the end of this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203771/local-coordinates-on-infinite-dimensional-lie-groups-factorization-of-riemann) and because the subject involves many deformations of shuffle, I came to the following

Let $k$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra and $\mathfrak{g}$ a $k$-Lie algebra, given any ordered basis $B=(b_i)_{i\in I}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, we will use the multiindex notation for the attached PBW basis
$$
B^{\alpha}=\prod^{\rightarrow}_{i\in supp(\alpha)}b_i^{\alpha(i)}
$$
where $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}$. We now note $(B_{\beta})_{\beta\in \mathbb{N}^{(I)}}$ the coordinate forms i.e.
$$
\langle B_{\beta} \mid B^{\alpha}\rangle = \delta_{\alpha,\beta}\qquad \mbox{(Kronecker delta)}\ .
$$
It is easy to see that, due to the combinatorial formula
$$
B_{\beta_1}\ast B_{\beta_2}=\binom{\beta_1+\beta_2}{\beta_1}B_{\beta_1+\beta_2}
$$
the span $\mathcal{A}$ of the forms $B_{\beta}$ is a $\ast$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{U}^*$.

**Proposition** Let $\mathcal{U}^*\otimes \mathcal{U}\hookrightarrow End(\mathcal{U})$ be the usual embedding (which has the space of finite ranked endomorphisms as image). We endow $End(\mathcal{U})$ with the topology of pointwise convergence ($\mathcal{U}$ being endowed with the discrete topology) so that $End(\mathcal{U})\simeq \mathcal{U}^*\hat{\otimes} \mathcal{U}$.

i) We have
$$
Id=\prod_{i\in I}^{\rightarrow} e^{B_{e_i} \otimes\,b_i}
$$
ii) If $\chi\ :\ \mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is a $\mathcal{B}$-valued character we have 
$$
\chi=\prod_{i\in I}^{\rightarrow} e^{\chi(B_{e_i})\,b_i}
$$ 
where $e_i(j)=\delta_{i,j}$.

**Question** If known, does someone has reference(s) for this proposition (or, at least (i) or (ii)) ?